# sed replace space character at the 8th position from selected text

Tags: linux, bash, vim, sed

I have a long list of hosts added in the config file of the dhcp server for our company.

The entries look like this:

```
host s1 { hardware ethernet b4:e1:0f:06:cb:83; fixed-address 192.168.10.43; }
host s2 { hardware ethernet b4:e1:0f:06:cb:90; fixed-address 192.168.10.64; }
host s3 { hardware ethernet b4:e1:0f:06:cb:9d; fixed-address 192.168.10.44; }
host s4 { hardware ethernet b4:e1:0f:06:cb:aa; fixed-address 192.168.10.65; }
host s5 { hardware ethernet b4:e1:0f:06:cb:b7; fixed-address 192.168.10.41; }
host s6 { hardware ethernet b4:e1:0f:06:cb:c4; fixed-address 192.168.10.35; }
host s7 { hardware ethernet b4:e1:0f:06:cb:d1; fixed-address 192.168.10.36; }
host s8 { hardware ethernet b4:e1:0f:06:cb:de; fixed-address 192.168.10.67; }
host s9 { hardware ethernet b4:e1:0f:06:cb:eb; fixed-address 192.168.10.72; }
```

I am editing the file using vim. How do i replace the space char at position 8 with something like .domain.com? (I am referring to the space char after s1,s2 etc

I have tried different configurations and patterns with sed but for some reason I cant' make it to work.

An alternative way would be to replace the space + { with what I want but this is not the solution I am looking for.

Regards,

Comment: sed -i 's/hardware/dom.com.hardware/g' file1

Comment: You have added vim as a tag. Can I answer it for vim?

Comment: I guess you could... I don't really know how this works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed 's/host [^ ]*/&.domain.com/g' file
```

Comment: could do `sed 's/ /.domain.com/2' file` instead.. (add a space after com if required)

Comment: I have tried your solution and in the end came up with: 
s/host [^ ]*/&.domain.com/g

Answer (score 3):

(This is a *Vim* answer)

You can substitute the first space after column 7 with:

```
:%s/\%>7c /.domain.com
```

But your lines won't be very pretty:

```
host s1.domain.com{ hardware ethernet b4:e1:0f:06:cb:83; fixed-address 192.168.10.43; }
```

Instead, you could leave that space alone with:

```
:%s/\%8c/.domain.com
```

and obtain this:

```
host s1.domain.com { hardware ethernet b4:e1:0f:06:cb:83; fixed-address 192.168.10.43; }
```

Or you could do it with a simple macro:

```
:%normal! 2f i.domain.com<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed, based on character count:

```
sed 's/\(.\{7\}\) /\1domain.com/' file
```

To edit the file *in place*, add the `-i` option:

```
sed -i 's/\(.\{7\}\) /\1domain.com/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

To add `.domain.com` to the second word on each line, with Vim:

```
:%s/\v^(\s*\w+){2}\zs/.domain.com/
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/ +/.domain.com /2' file.txt
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ $2 = $2 ".domain.com" } 1' file.txt
```