# Sed: global substitution - how to ignore a particular range of positions in one particular line

Tags: regex, search, sed

I want to do a globel substitution of *all* occurrances of string "apple" to "banana", *except* for the *second* occurance of "apple" in line 214. The second occurance of "apple" has the line position of 13 to 17.

For example, line 214 looks like this right now:

```
apple.pineapplejuice();
```

I want this line to be changed to (the "apple" in "pineapplejuice() is not changed"

```
banana.pineapplejuice();
```

Some example usage of `apple` in the rest of my file

```
SetupTable(apple, {isWashed, okay});
```

I have tried finding answers in these posts, but cannot find what I need:
[sed replace space character at the 8th position from selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244106/sed-replace-space-character-at-the-8th-position-from-selected-text) / [How to use sed and cut to find and replace value at certain position of line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430208/how-to-use-sed-and-cut-to-find-and-replace-value-at-certain-position-of-line-in)

Code that I have tried:

```
sed -i -e '214\{13,17\}!s/apple/banana/g' src/test/fruit.cpp
```

and i got

```
sed: 1: "214\{13,17\}!s/apple/ba ...": invalid command code \
```

I think I just need to know how to specify the address of a particular range of characters on a particular line to make this work, but maybe there are other more clever approaches than this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you match the word apple? Ie. `apple` that before the word and after the word is a non-word character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is a (turing complete) scripting language. You can write conditions:

```
sed '
   214{
      # line 214 handled spexially
      s/apple/banana/
   }
   214!{
      # all except line 214
      s/apple/banana/g
   }
'
```

or you could `'214{s/apple/banana;b;}; s/apple/banana/g'` jump to beginning of the script if 214 line is found.

I believe you just want to use GNU sed extensions and match the word `apple`:

```
sed 's/\<apple\>/banana/g'
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I will look into scripts. I did try `sed -i -e '214!s/\<apple\>/banana/g' src/test/fruit.cpp`  but running this line somehow does nothing in my code at all. Perhaps I am missing some configurations...?

Comment: Well, `sed -e '214!s/\<apple\>/banana/g' <<<'apple'` works in my bash.

Answer (score 0):

In GNU sed, replace `apple` as a whole word with

```
sed -i 's/\bapple\b/banana/g' file
```

`\b` is a word boundary.